# How to write the update query to update target table column A with values 'Y' or 'N' based on if it exists or not in source table

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to update column A of my target table with values 'Y' if the key_id_column exists in (SELECT ID_COLUMN FROM SOURCE_TBL) and with values 'N' if it does not exists in (SELECT ID_COLUMN FROM SOURCE_TBL)

Comment: Did not understand! can you give an example query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Teradata- but I just want to know how to write a update query with the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
update target_table 
set target_column = case when target_column in (select column from source_table) then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

hope this works

Comment: This logic looks correct.  Why would the update fail?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to manage an `OUTER JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement on Teradata. You may need to tweak it a bit, but it should get you along down the road a bit further.

```
UPDATE target_table 
   SET target_column = DT.indicator_column
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN tgt.key_id_column is not null
                    THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N'
                END as indicator_column
          FROM source_table src
          LEFT JOIN
               target_table tgt
            ON src.id_column = tgt.key_id_column) DT;
```

Comment: NOT WORKING -  its updating only rows which are present in both tables.

Comment: Can you setup a SQL fiddle with sample data?